# Listening event for select id updates

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code...

```js
var currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === false && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
  loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
} else if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
  var currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue + '.hidden';
  loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
} else if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === true) {
  var currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue + '.hidden.unlisted';
  loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
} else if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === false && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === true) {
  var currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue + '.unlisted';
  loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
}

document.getElementById("hidden").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
  if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
    var currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue + '.hidden';
    loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
  } else if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === false && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === false) {
    loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
  } else if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === true && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === true) {
    var currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue + '.hidden.unlisted';
    loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
  } else if (document.getElementById("hidden").checked === false && document.getElementById("unlisted").checked === true) {
    var currentBaseValue = currentBaseValue + '.unlisted';
    loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectedBaseRelease">
  <option value="url1">A</option>
  <option value="url2" selected>B</option>
  <option value="url3">C</option>
  <option value="url4">D</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, there are "hidden" and "unlisted" (checkboxes) that are defined as listening events. When the checkboxes are activated and deactivated, everything is totally fine--I see the changes that I expect. However, when the select id choice changes, from, say, D to A, the status of the checkboxes is not processed, even though I thought the code that immediately follows the select id section would cover that condition.

But the code that follows the select section has no listening-like declarations. How can I make sure that every time the select id value changes the current status of the checkboxes will be processed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include all relevant code? You mention several hidden fields yet they aren't in your example. Please remember to include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Chris if you try the modification below and it doesn't help you unravel the mystery feel free to ping me on here and I'll be happy to try to help...

Comment: @Adam the fields are not hidden--that is the name of an input checkbox. "hidden," in this context, is related to a type of file that needs to be sourced. Sorry if that caused any confusion.

Comment: @Chris can you please confirm whether my answer solves your problem or not, and if not can you please further clarify your problem?

Comment: @duhaime yes, I was able to get it to work. In short, as you encouraged, wrapping a     
document.querySelector("#selectedBaseRelease").addEventListener("change", function(event) {...});     ...around the first block of code in the OP made the biggest difference. You can look at lines 185~199 and 238~252 here: https://jsfiddle.net/e4bunLvh/54/ Note that I cannot get the jsfiddle code to source other URLs (lines 7~12), so you can only see the basic layout when running the script. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Chris excellent. In that case, can you please click the big green check mark next to my answer so other users will know this issue has been resolved? It would be great if you could do that on all questions you've asked that are now answered!

Comment: @duhaime Done! Thanks again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up this code a bit can help make the problem simpler. Here I've attached the event listener to each of the inputs, so you can clearly see how we respond to state changes:

```js
var unlisted = document.querySelector('#unlisted');
var hidden = document.querySelector('#hidden');
var text = document.querySelector('#text');
var select = document.querySelector('#select');

[hidden, unlisted, select].forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var baseVal = select.value;
    if (hidden.checked) baseVal += '.hidden';
    if (unlisted.checked) baseVal += '.unlisted'
    loadBaseText(baseVal);
  });
})

function loadBaseText(s) {
  text.textContent = s; 
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="url1">A</option>
  <option value="url2" selected >B</option>
  <option value="url3">C</option>
  <option value="url4">D</option>
</select>

<div>Hidden</div>
<input id='hidden' type='checkbox' />

<div>Unlisted</div>
<input id='unlisted' type='checkbox' />

<div>Result</div>
<div id='text' />
```